# Using Threads to get Data

Tags: asp.net, mysql, multithreading

In a project on `asp.net` and `mysql`, we need data from 4 different databases. For that we use the main thread, and get each datatable one by one in sequence and processes it. Now we need to optimize it, and we  assume that we can save time by using threads to get datatables.

The main problem, I am assuming, how we let main thread to wait for all threads to complete? 
 Any Idea? 
 Thanks.

Comment: This question might help you : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360789/in-c-wait-on-the-mainthread-while-continuing-to-process-ui-updates-net-2-0**. Also, I think [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) will be a good option for these kind of operations